# Does core web vitals field data consider network speed?

Tags: seo, core-web-vitals

Google measures core web vitals based on real-world metrics (like when users visit pages in their Chrome browsers). But what if a user browses from a location where network connection is poor? Does Google adjust for the network connection speed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google's Search Advocate, John Mueller, [stated last April](https://youtu.be/mequMsZo0WI?t=300) that users' connection speed does have an affect on your field data. In that video, he says:

> If 90% of your users are coming from locations that are slow and
> essentially 90% of your users have this sub-optimal experience with
> your site, then that’s what will be taken into account.

That statement lines up with Google's documentation on [core web vitals thresholds](https://web.dev/defining-core-web-vitals-thresholds/), which states that the 75th percentile value of all page views will be used to classify the site's overall performance.

There are issues inherent in this setup, which the person in the video brings up when discussing it with Mueller.

The rollout of core web vitals ranking still seems to be an evolving situation, and so it is possible that Google will take a more nuanced approach to last-mile latency. So, hopefully this answer does not age well.

Comment: I hope the 75th percentile value threshold should help sites that serve globally to countries including the poor speed ones https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_Internet_connection_speeds. I have a doubt. Does core web vitals measured in a location (e.g., a country with poor speed) is going to affect rankings only around that location? I think this question is important in the context of the ongoing page experience update.

Comment: Google says that core vitals will be a minor ranking factor, so I wouldn't worry too much about it.  Between this issue of users' connection speeds and the scant data coverage they have for most pages, there is no way they are going to be able to ramp it up significantly.